# Services has been closed Vs Services are shutdown

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

I need to inform a group of people via email about some services which can no longer be provided/available to them. Now I am confused whether i should use "has been closed" or "services are shutdown". 
I don't want to use word terminated, as it usually create a negative impact and let the other feel about some inappropriate/untimely action. Rather the service is not available because the company has decided to close the service and will not be available anymore for anyone.

Comment: *That service has been discontinued.* OR: *Those services have been discontinued.*

Comment: if anything, 'shut down'. 'shutdown' is a noun, "shutdown of the services occurred". And usually, 'shut down' in the context like you want it will mean 'terminated by external party' - "The Police shut down an amphetamine lab."

Comment: I agree with Jim, but would add that unless we see the entire draft (which would be proofreading), we can't tell if "discontinued" is the most appropriate word. You could use "no longer available", "no longer accessible", "no longer provided", etc. It all depends on the tense, point of view, and the context of the service, the nature of the service, who did what to make it "go away", and the relation of you and the user to the service. I can give many examples of why it can be that nuanced.

Comment: I can not define the services exactly, but it is with accessing credit points earned prior to a specific period. Anyway I agree with Jim's draft and used "service has been discontinued". Thanks @Jim.

Answer (score 1):

No...don't go for service shut down, it does not have a shutter! :)

Generally, we say it in these many ways...

> The service has been discontinued *(Jim)* 
>  The service is no longer available *(Gary)*

Or, I may also say...

> They don't offer the service anymore 
>  They have stopped providing the service

Comment: I like your phrase "They don't offer the services anymore". But it would have been a great help if you would have suggested it bit earlier.  Still I upvote your answer.